# How to describe a person who loves normal room temperature that’s 79 to 84 degrees?

Tags: word-choice

How can I describe a person who likes a room temperature between 79 and 84 °F [26 and 29 °C]?

The person dislikes any temperature beyond this range.

Comment: In what context do you want to use this word? That might help in answering the question.

Comment: @Flimzy, I want to use a word to describe a person that have this strange reaction: In a temperature below 26 degree Celsius, the person body (from head to toe) become so cold that you thought you have touch a ice. However, in the temperature above 29 degree Celsius, you can see the person sweating and the body become very hot. Hope that this will help you in answering my question.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll think on it.  Slightly related, someone who is comfortable in cold temperature is often said to be "cold blooded" and someone comfortable in warm temperature, "warm-blooded."

Comment: But the problem now is that the person is neither a "cold blooded" nor "warm-blooded". The person is in between and right now I have two choice - one to use 'Normal' or use 'Mesophilic'. Definitely, not the word 'normal-blooded' cause I will LOL.

Comment: Well, you'd call them hot-blooded, then break into a Foreigner rendition complete with air guitar. https://youtu.be/5c1m2BAg2Sc You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Normal," of course, unless the person is from a different planet.

Comment: Actually I have a word for it - **Mesophilic** but a quick check show that it prefer temperature of 30 - 37 Degree Celsius (although the whole temperature range from 25 - 40 Degree Celsius)

Comment: +1 I will take the word `Normal` as the person is not well-verse in English.

Comment: Normal, really? Most people I know find room temperatures above 26°C uncomfortably warm… it's different if you're outside with a breeze, at the beach, etc.

Comment: 68 to 73 is normal. You're talking about a level of heat that's much too warm for most people.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Kris answer, my another alternative word would be - **Mesophilic**

I am still open for a better word choice (if there are).

Comment: I love that word.  I learned it recently while reading about fermenting dairy products, and have just been waiting for a chance to use it to describe people. I almost provided an answer... but then I saw that you beat me to it. I also like the noun form... "mesophile" because it just sounds naughty.

Comment: I must also add, you probably shouldn't use that word in any context where you expect non-biologists to have any idea what you're talking about. The dictionary says it is primarily, or even specifically, a biology term. So applying it to people is really a metaphorical use of the word more than a technically proper one.

Comment: @Flimzy, actually I want to answer my question but I am not sure if there are even better word to best describe the person that I mention in my question. Thank you for loving that word. (Spend quite some time before I find it.) I agree with you that the word is really a metaphorical use but I could not find any better except using the word 'Normal' at this time of moment.

Comment: @Flimzy, why would it be metaphoric? Biology studies "life and living organisms". It is rare [though](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mesophilic%2Ccheimaphobia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Unreason: You're right, I should have said it is "primarily a microbiology term"

Answer (score 2):

I would describe such a person as *sensitive to even mild fluctuations in temperature*.

*Temperature-sensitive* is more concise, but less specific option; it's also a [medical term](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/temperature-sensitive).

Comment: I can't really said that the person is sensitive to mild fluctuations in temperature cause if it is, then a quick change of temperature from 27 degree to 29 degree or 28 degree to 26 degree will make the person feel uncomfortable even though the temperature fluctuate little but is still in the person's acceptable temperature.

Comment: I think if your acceptable range is 4 degrees, you are sensitive to mild fluctuations.

Comment: Is there any word that does not make one feel that it belong to a medical term or biology term cause I don't want to hurt that person feeling.

Comment: I can't imagine anyone aware of the fact that they hate temperatures outside of a set range would be offended by being called *temperature-sensitive*. It's entirely neutral.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: I don't think 4 degrees of comfort is a narrow range. (For those using Fahrenheit: it's 7.2 degrees F; the range in F is 78.8 to 84.2.) People from some countries may prefer different ranges, but if you consider (say) what temperature you'd like to set your AC to, I don't think this is a narrow range.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR 84.2 minus 78.8 is 5.4 not 7.2; let's just call it five degrees, and use whole numbers.

Comment: @tchrist 4 Celsius degrees are 7.2 Fahrenheit degrees. My point was that  this is not very narrow, for someone's range. (The other range 78.8 °F to 84.2 °F that I mentioned seems to be 26 °C to 29 °C, which is only 3 Celsius degrees, which is 5.4 Fahrenheit degrees. Not sure why I mentioned it. Anyway, I have a less strong opinion about whether that one is narrow.)